# Powershell replace multiple occurrences of regex in text file

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, match

I have a huge file with the index of a book and I need to subtract 2 to all numbers. Each line may have more numbers like:

> Surname, Name 12, 17-33
>    Second, Name 75

and I need them to become

> Surname, Name 10, 15-31
>    Second, Name 73

I have written this small script using references around in order to do the task:

```
`$trova = "[0-9]+(?![^<>]*>)"
(Get-Content D:\path\document.xml) |
Foreach-Object {if ($_ -match "$trova"){
$cambia= $matches[0]
$cambia-=2
$_ -replace $trova, $cambia}
} | 
Set-Content D:\path\document2.xml`
```

The problem is that I can only successfully match the first one of each line, than all the substitution are with the same number, thus

> Surname, Name 10, 10-10
>    Second, Name 73

I'm a bit stuck. I have seen some suggestion to use

```
Select-String $trova -input $string -AllMatches
```

but I cannot see how to properly make it work in order to do the math before doing the substitution. The file is the xml from a docx document (I need to retain the style) but I decided to work directly from powershell instead of using the Word.Application because it seemed easier (this is why my regex avoid the numbers inside a tag). Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I cannot understand how my question could be a duplicate. The problem is not the regex, it is the match part, I believe.

Comment: The short of it: `-match` only ever matches (at most) _one_ occurrence, and while `-replace` finds _all_ matches, it doesn't support performing arbitrary calculations/transformations on each match, in _Windows PowerShell_ (unlike in PowerShell _Core_); that's where `[regex]::Replace()` comes in, as demonstrated in the accepted answer to the linked question.

Comment: Thank you very much! it took me a while but I finally got it! It was the first approach, a lot simpler! now code is `$trova = "[0-9]+(?![^<>]*>)"
$testo = Get-Content D:\path\document.xml 
[regex]::Replace("$testo", "$trova", {param($match) [int] $match.Value -2}) |
Set-Content D:\path\document2.xml`

Comment: Exactly, you were just following the wrong path, and the other thread showed the correct one. You already had all you need to get it working using the callback.